# goaccess parsing not working

Tags: apache, logging, goaccess

I'm trying to get goaccess working.
Already take some time on docs and examples but without success.

Basically i have log lines like:

```
10031488_71334 xpto.domain.com 88.103.999.999 - - [16/Jun/2013:15:03:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5624 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" -
```

and already compile goaccess and create a conf file:

```
cat ~/.goaccessrc
date_format %d/%b/%Y:%T %z
log_format %^ %^ %h - - [$d] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %^
```

Then i got:

```
./goaccess -a -f miniout.log

GoAccess - version 0.6 - Aug  5 2013 20:20:16

An error has occurred
Error occured at: goaccess.c - render_screens - 358
Message: Nothing valid to process.
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: `[$d]` ?  Didn't see the `$` symbol in GoAccess man.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the global options use --no-global-config option with goaccess.
I am using this to process my log files on a day by day basis:

```
grep --color=auto `date +"%d/%b"` /var/log/nginx/sitename.access.log | goaccess --no-global-config > report.html
```

goaccess version : 0.8

Answer (score 1):

Solved by log format change to:

```
log_format %^ %^ %h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
date_format %d/%b/%Y
```

Answer (score 1):

First, review you log configuration in httpd.conf or into the sites configuration files for vhost.

then follow the next logics.

combinedvhost apache log format configuration:

%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\

to goaccess:

apache - what is? - how in goaccess

%v - vhost - %^ ignore it

%h - host - %h

%l - hyphen - %^ ignore it

%u - user - %^ ignore it

%t - timestamp - [%d:t% %^] ignore the zone from apache log

%r - request - %r

%s - status - %s

%b - size - %b

%{referer}i - request header - %R

%{UAgent}i - user agent - %u

goaccess.conf

**log-format %^ %h %^ %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"**

1. Note that in %r, %R and %u you will need "", because those are text fields (i think)
2. Note that between %u and date, there is not space (i do not know why...)

with:

time-format %H:%M:%S

date-format %d/%b/%Y

Reference:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

http://goaccess.io/man